# Avoid interpreting HTML code in a QTextBrowser

Tags: html, qt

I have a QTextBrowser in my Qt application. I would like to append some text but, I need part of this text not to be interpreted in HTML. How can I achieve this? May I encode the QString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your browser not to interpret only parts of your text as HTML you will need to quote the part you want to omit (replace "<" with "&l t;" etc.). You can use convenient escape method:

```
textBrowser->insertHtml(
    QString("<b>this will be bold</b>") + 
    Qt::escape(QString("<b>this will not</b>"))
);
```

If you would like not to interpret the whole thing you can insert it as plain text:

```
textBrowser->insertPlainText ( "<b>foobar</b>" );
```

Comment: Note that in Qt5 you'd better use `str.toHtmlEscaped()` instead of `Qt::escape(str)` since the latter is deprecated and seems to not be available in 5.0.1.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem before reading this answer but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my own question using:

```
QString codedHtml = Qt::escape(html);
```